# Zeoslib fails to read LargeInt fields from sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe2, zeos

I'm trying to read sqlite database with ZeosLib components and Delphi XE2. Everything works perfectly, except when I try to read three timestamp values that are stored, which are basically 17 digit numbers. Instead getting the proper value, I get zero. Function that reads database data (watch for commented lines):

```
procedure TCookieImporter.LoadCookies(const AChromeDatabase: String);
var
  zconn          : TZConnection;
  zquery         : TZReadOnlyQuery;
  creation_utc   : Int64;
  expires_utc    : Int64;
  last_access_utc: Int64;
  host_key       : String;
  name           : String;
  value          : String;
  path           : String;
  secure         : Integer;
  httponly       : Integer;
  has_expires    : Integer;
  persistent     : Integer;
  priority       : Integer;
  cookie         : TChromeCookie;
begin
  zconn := TZConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    zconn.Protocol := 'sqlite-3';
    zconn.Database := AChromeDatabase;
    zconn.Connect;
    if zconn.Connected then
    try
      zquery := TZReadOnlyQuery.Create(nil);
      try
        zquery.Connection := zconn;
        zquery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM cookies';
        zquery.Active := TRUE;
        while not zquery.Eof do
        begin
          // bug: following three lines - they all return zero
          creation_utc := zquery.FieldByName('creation_utc').AsLargeInt;
          expires_utc := zquery.FieldByName('expires_utc').AsLargeInt;
          last_access_utc := zquery.FieldByName('last_access_utc').AsLargeInt;

          // debug info for SO
          WriteLn(zquery.FieldDefs[0].Name); // = creation_utc
          WriteLn(zquery.FieldDefs[0].Size); // = 0
          WriteLn(zquery.FieldByName('creation_utc').AsString); // = 0
          WriteLn(VarToStr(zquery.FieldValues['creation_utc'])); // = 0
          dt := zquery.FieldDefs[0].DataType; // dt = ftInteger

          host_key := zquery.FieldByName('host_key').AsString;
          name := zquery.FieldByName('name').AsString;
          value := zquery.FieldByName('value').AsString;
          path := zquery.FieldByName('path').AsString;
          secure := zquery.FieldByName('secure').AsInteger;
          httponly := zquery.FieldByName('httponly').AsInteger;
          has_expires := zquery.FieldByName('has_expires').AsInteger;
          persistent := zquery.FieldByName('persistent').AsInteger;
          priority := zquery.FieldByName('priority').AsInteger;

          cookie := TChromeCookie.Create(creation_utc, host_key, name, value, path, expires_utc, secure, httponly, last_access_utc, has_expires, persistent, priority);
          FChromeCookies.Add(cookie);

          zquery.Next;
        end;
      finally
        zquery.Free;
      end;
    finally
      zconn.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    zconn.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I've tried everything that came to my mind, from simply getting value with `.AsLargeInt()` getter, to getting it as `Variant`, then casting to `Integer`/`Int64`/`String`, etc.. In all cases, I got zero as return value. I've also tried with different versions of ZeosLib, specifically `7.0.6-stable` and `7.1.1-rc` ones. Wasn't able to compile with `6.6.6-stable` one due to incompatibility with newer versions of Delphi.

Here is how data looks like when I open it with SQLite Manager (firefox addon):

[image: cookies table data]

And table structure:

[image: cookies table structure]

I've tried another approach, by reading data with `DISqlite3` components, and they work, however they are shareware and I'd rather go with freeware ones if possible.

Any ideas what is causing this weird bug?

Comment: Try trunc(...AsDouble). Not perfect but may work. OR our Open Source classes, for direct access to SQlite3 with full speed - see http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/22/SynDBSQLite3%3A-SQLite3-direct-access - and not problem with Int64 large numbers. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll give SynDBSQLite3 a go now. Trunc() didn't do the trick btw.

Comment: try defining the fields as BIGINT; see the post here: http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1275

Comment: database is external, so I can't edit it - however, SynDBSQLite seems to work flawlessly :)

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez do you have a minute to review this and give me your opinion if I can improve it somehow? I find it hard to find proper sqlite mORMot examples on internet: http://pastebin.com/8xq0N9cb

Comment: You have transaction methods available. The rest sounds OK. See also exclusive mode for best speed. Our blog has some articles and also the mORMot doc is exhaustive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I created thread on their official forum and got following response:

> Zeos is a common access component. I know we could assume Int64 types for the Integer fields.
>
> Actually we use BIGINT to assume TLongInt-Fields. Which the most RDBM's are using for.
>
> This is an open discussion. Internaly SQLite accepts two Integer-bindings for prepared statments. Not a problem to make this patch..
>
> So others can post here if we should change this or not. On 7.2 if you doubt, not on 7.0 or 7.1. Think about: This is a long-standing code. And it could make loads of trouble if the users do update there components.

[[link to the thread](http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=4765&e=0)]